# Preference getView() android

Tags: android

I need to change the image of an ImageView placed inside a custom preference. I am doing this:

```
View thumb1 = findViewById(R.id.thumb_1);
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) thumb1.getParent();
final Preference myPref = (Preference) findPreference("test02");
((ImageView) myPref.getView(thumb1, vg)).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_chooser);
```

I get a null error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should add some checks in there to make sure that `myPref` and `myPref.getView()` are not null

Answer (score 0):

perference.getView(null,null).findViewById(R.id.xx);

Answer (score -1):

Well, I did in this way in `Kotlin`.

This sample has **custom layout** for **Preference** and update it in any **function**.

**Preference XML:**

```
<Preference
   android:key="preference_key"
   android:layout="@layout/custom_layout_name"
   android:summary="Summary"
   android:title="Title" />
```

**custom_layout_name.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/preference_margin_top_bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/preference_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/preference_margin_top_bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/colorView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/preference_color_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/preference_color_size"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/preference_margin_top_bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Class:**

```
private var preferenceColor: Preference? = null

preferenceColor = preferenceManager.findPreference("preference_key)
preferenceColor!!.onPreferenceClickListener = Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {
     anyFunction(Color.BLUE)
  true
}
```

**Function for updating the View:**

```
private fun anyFunction(color: Int) {
        val colorViewOrigin = findViewById<View>(R.id.colorView)
        val colorViewParent: ViewGroup = colorViewOrigin.parent as ViewGroup
        val preferenceManager = preferenceColor?.getPreferenceManager()
        val colorView = preferenceManager?.findPreference("preference_key")!!.getView(colorViewOrigin, colorViewParent) as View
        colorView.setBackgroundColor(color)
}
```

Hope it would be help you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I use more updated version of Kotlin/android but there is no option to call getView after finding the preference